# socket.io client receiving multiple calls to same event in react native

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, socket.io, socket.io-1.0

Whenver the user login into the application. he joins to its own userId in server via

```
socket.join(uid)
```

whereas the nodejs endpoint looks like

```
router.post("/secured/postmessage", (req,res)=>{
  const { message, receiverId } = req.body;

 io.to(receiverId).emit("newMessage", {
      msgBody: message,
      sender: req.currentUser,
    });
})
```

now the RN part:

Chat screen functional Component looks like

```
export default function Chat({ navigation }) {

//receiveing the socket as props from previous screen
  const { contact, socket } = navigation.state.params;
  // console.log("in conversation contact is ", contact);


  const [data, setData] = useState([
    {
      id: 8,
      date: "9:50 am",
      type: "in",
      message: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit a met",
    },
  ]);

//this gets fired multiple times <--------
socket.on("newMessage", ({ msgBody, sender }) => {
    setData((oldMessages) => [...oldMessages, msgBody]);
  });

//handleSubmit gets fired when user types message and press SEND
const handleSubmit(){
//sending the post request to server with message
 axios.post(baseUrl + "/secured/postmessage", {
    message: message,
    receiverId: contact._id,
    })
}
return(
  ...
  )
```

whereas the nodejs endpoint looks like

```
router.post("/secured/postmessage", (req,res)=>{
 io.to(receiverId).emit("newMessage", {
      msgBody: messageResult,
      sender: req.currentUser,
    });
})
```

socket.on('newMessage') in Chat screen is getting fired multiple times, I dont know why

Comment: Are you calling the function `Chat()` more than once?  If so, you're registering a new `socket.on("newMessage", ...)` handler each time and they accumulate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can try adding socket event handler only when your Chat component mounted.
In functional component, you can use React.useEffect().

refer to below

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("newMessage", ({ msgBody, sender }) => {
        setData((oldMessages) => [...oldMessages, msgBody]);
    });
},[]);
```

Comment: worked like a charm but can you explain why? as per my understanding useEffect hook is called when the component gets mounted succesfully. but here we are continuously listening for socket event. So on every call to socket event ,is the component remounted or updated ?

Comment: as far as i know, socket.on('newMessage'..) statement will be executed whenever your compoment rerendered.   
  
this means attaching 'newMessage' event handler can be occurred multiple times.
so i thought it is better to attach event handler only when component mounted by passing `[]` as second argument of useEffect.